# MySQL select columns with CASE on joined tables

Tags: mysql, select, join, case

I'm trying to use a CASE statement depending on the information inside a column. 
If the column `artiesten.artiestennaam` IS NOT NULL, I would like this column to be selected. But *if this column is empty*, I would like to select another joined column: `personen.naam`

Is something like this even possible? It's also fine if the column `personen.naam` is selected, but empty if `artiesten.artiestennaam` IS NOT NULL.

I did figured out something like shown below.

```
SELECT 
  groeperingen.groeperingsnaam, nummers.naam,

CASE WHEN artiesten.artiestennaam IS NOT NULL 
  THEN artiesten.artiestennaam
  ELSE personen.naam

FROM artiesten_nummers
  JOIN artiesten ON artiesten_nummers.artiestenID = artiesten.ID
      LEFT JOIN personen ON personen.ID = artiesten.personenID
  JOIN nummers ON artiesten_nummers.nummersID = nummers.ID
      LEFT JOIN groeperingen ON groeperingen.ID = nummers.groeperingenID
```

To be clear: if the column `artiestennaam` is filled in I would like the column `naam` to be empty or not selected. And vice versa: if `artiestennaam` is empty I would like `naam` to show up.

Comment: you forgot END CASE at the end of your case statement. Also you don't need a case statement. you can use the IFNULL function.

Comment: Wow. So stupid. Did cost me like half an hour.. Thanks for your reply! ;)

Comment: no worries, glad to help.

Comment: voting to close as a TYPO error